# How to check symbols in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm beginner in programming (specially in C++). I've tried to check incoming symbols for letters. I need to "catch" only numbers from 0 to 9. So, i try to use it:

```
// Checking "a". If "a" is a letter, the error must be printed;
if (a!='%d') {
    cout << "pfff! U cant use letters!" << endl;
    return -1;
}
// The end of checking;
```

But it doesn't work. I guess that i can't use '%d' in C++. How i can say:
"Check all symbols and stop the program if there will be non-numbers."

P.S. Sorry for my english. I hope u got me.

Comment: this may help: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isalpha/

Comment: '%d' is within quotes, that makes it a string/set of chars.Kindly try to use it without the quotes

Comment: Added an working example. hope this helps you .

Comment: You are trying to use regex it seems, which is not how you do it in C++

Comment: @Pavel : If any answer here, helps you in any way, then accept the answer by clicking on the right side(you will get a tick icon). This will help other people to straight away look at the better answer .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes , [`isdigit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) will work out nicely here .

An example is :

```
    #inlude <iostream>
    #include <ctype.h>
    // in ctype.h is located the isdigit() function
    using namespace std;
    //...
    char test;
    int x;
    cin >> test;
    if ( isdigit(test) )//tests wether test is == to '0', '1', '2' ...
    {
          cin>>putback(test);//puts test back to the stream
          cin >> x;
    }
    else
         errorMsg();
```

Comment: Why didn't you use the `operator>>` also at `cin.get(test);`, i.e. `cin>>text;`?

Comment: ahhh, sorry bad habits, kind a java man, so sometimes i make such stupid mistakes. Thanks for pointing it out though. Will change it right away .

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) instead.

```
if (!isdigit(a)) {
    cout << "pfff! U cant use letters!" << endl;
    return -1;
}
```

The text in your `cout` suggests you're looking for `isalpha` though:

```
if (isalpha(a)) {
    cout << "pfff! U cant use letters!" << endl;
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `isdigit()` from the inherited C library. This is present in the header *cctype*. The logic of the algorithm you are asking for would be to run over the string entered and react when the character is not a digit.

Here you are a sample source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    int toret = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    std::string str;

    std::getline( std::cin, str );

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        if ( !std::isdigit( str[ i ] ) ) {
            std::cerr << "Only digits allowed" << std::endl;
            toret = EXIT_FAILURE;
            break;
        }
    }

    return toret;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You must use function [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit).

```
if (!isdigit(a)) {
    cout << "pfff! U cant use letters!" << endl;
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something you could also do is to do the opposite of the your code. To check wether the input is equal or bigger than 0 and also smaller than 10 for example.

If that is the case it's a number ranging from 0 to 9, if it's not then the input was wrong.